# Orchard module development and cache.dat

Tags: asp.net-mvc, module, orchardcms

I'm writing a custom module with orchard.
I have created a solution pointing to Orchard Web Binaries and placing my module as a subdir od Modules directory.
This module livies happly in its own project.
I can build it and I can browse Orchard with my module.
So far so good.
But the problem is that every time i rebuild my module I have to remove cache.dat file in App_data in order to have Orchard loading changed module.
This is really annoying and time consuming.
Is there a better way to develop Orchard modules so that every time i build Orchard uses the new version?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more context? Are you using full Orchard source code for developing modules locally? Are you rebuilding the whole solution or just your module? Are you using IIS/IIS Express or Cassini (VS built-in web server) for development? Are you restarting the application after rebuilding your module?

Comment: I'm using cassini. I just build (re-build) my module. I do not restart cassini. I'm not using full orchard source, just binaries. Is there an easy way to restart the app? I just searching a quick way to develop a module. Changing a view and reload is immediate, changing *.cs and rebuild requires too much time for a developing session.... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enable dynamic compilation:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation

Look at \Config\HostComponents.config and set Disabled value to false